# Multiple conditional statement on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want a column `"PRI/TEN"`.

1. when column PRIMARY RESOURCE contains `"BERIX"`, `PRI/TEN` should
   have `"TBC"`.
2. when column PRIMARY RESOURCE contains`"BERIXTVX"`,
   `PRI/TEN` should have `"TEN"`.
3. when column PRIMARY RESOURCE contains
   `"BERIXVX"`, `PRI/TEN` should have `"PRI"`.

I tried:

```
data1['PRI/ TEN'] = np.where(data1['First']!='BERIXVX', 'PRI','TEN')
```

This is my original column

```
Primary Resource
BERIX_MYANMAR ONLY
BERIXTVX_BOOST IPV
BERIXTVX_BOOST IPV
BERIXVX_ENCEPUR A AD
BERIXVX_ENCEPUR AD
BERIXTVX_BOOST IPV
BERIXTVX_BEXSERO
```

This is what i want

```
Primary Resource    PRI/TEN
BERIX_MYANMAR ONLY  TBC
BERIXTVX_BOOST IPV  TEN
BERIXTVX_BOOST IPV  TEN
BERIXVX_ENCEPUR A AD    PRI
BERIXVX_ENCEPUR AD  PRI
BERIXTVX_BOOST IPV  TEN
BERIXTVX_BEXSERO    TEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def categorizer(row):
    if 'BERIXTVX' in row:
        return 'TEN'
    elif 'BERIXVX' in row:
        return 'PRI'
    elif 'BERIX' in row:
        return 'TBC'

    # Return a default value
    return None


data1['PRI/TEN'] = data1['PRIMARY RESOURCE'].apply(categorizer)
```

This applies the function `categorizer` on every row in the `PRIMARY RESOURCE` column. It's not vectorized though, so if let me know you if are having performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
m1 = df['Primary Resource'].str.contains('BERIX_')
m2 = df['Primary Resource'].str.contains('BERIXTVX_')
m3 = df['Primary Resource'].str.contains('BERIXVX_')

df['PRI/TEN'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['TBC', 'TEN', 'PRI'])

print(df)
       Primary Resource PRI/TEN
0    BERIX_MYANMAR ONLY     TBC
1    BERIXTVX_BOOST IPV     TEN
2    BERIXTVX_BOOST IPV     TEN
3  BERIXVX_ENCEPUR A AD     PRI
4    BERIXVX_ENCEPUR AD     PRI
5    BERIXTVX_BOOST IPV     TEN
6      BERIXTVX_BEXSERO     TEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all the answer. I got this on internet and it's doing the task.

It's just the normal where function with multiple nested where clause.

data1['Private/ Tender'] = np.where(data1['First']=='BERIXVX','PRI',
                                     (np.where(data1['First']=='BERIXTVX','TEN','TBC')))